# How do I do $this->model->getList() in php

Tags: php, undefined

I am working on i MVC and i've gone through some project to see how works but, when i do something like `$this->model->getList()` to get a list of items from my DB in my controller i get this error message

```
Notice: Undefined property: Managemenu::$model in C:\wamp\www\mymvc\Admin\controllers\managemenu.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function getList() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\mymvc\Admin\controllers\managemenu.php on line 10
```

Actually this is my code on my `managemenu` model

```
<?php class Managemenu_Model extends Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function getList(){
    $menus = Menu::find_all();
    return $menus;
}
public function edit(){
}
public function update(){
}
public function save(){
}
public function delete(){
}
}?>
```

and this is what my controller is like

```
<?php class Managemenu extends Controller{
public $mymenus = null;
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->index();
}
public function index(){
    @$this->loadModel("managemenu");
    $this->mymenus = $this->model->getList();
    $this->view->render("managemenu/index");
}
public function doList(){
}}?>
```

Also, I want to get the list of my menus on the front end by looping through the `$mymenus` into a table if i do `foreach($this->mymenus as....)` i keep on having the same error in my view template too

can anybody give me a hand. i don't know why that error comes up

Comment: Where comes menu comes from in this line `$menus = Menu::find_all();` ?

Comment: `$model` is not a property of `Managemenu`. That is the error you get. Is `loadModel()` supposed to set it? Remove that `@` in your code, write code that doesn't throw warnings.

Comment: Please share the code for `loadModel`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)